# Increase pressure on. Vitodens 200w boiler

Tags: boiler, pressure, gauge

I have a vitodens 200-w boiler with 4 zones. The pressure gauge reads 0 so no heat. I can hear water flowing through the pipes.
How do I increase the pressure? Or do I need to call a repair company?
I live in Michigan. We have hot water.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The image is of insufficient detail to reveal anything useful. Please [edit] to provide a larger one. But likely if your heat is out and you have no idea how the boiler system is pressurized calling somone will be the faster fix. This answer *might* help you if you can find similar parts that I don't see in your picture: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/84369/18078

Comment: This answer may also be useful: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/214595/18078

Comment: @Ecnerwal comments shall not be used as Answers, you should know that by now.

Comment: @Ruskes  Ecnerwal  didn't answer the question, he just pointed the OP in the direction to get more information. That's why he used the comments.