# I have a S-25 BF on my boiler. Downstairs is hot , upstairs -nothing. Could the impeller be bad and won't push to second floor?

Tags: hvac, hydronic

I have a S-25 BF pump.  Downstairs is heating fine. Not getting any heat to second floor. Tried bleeding upstairs, nothing came out. No air or water.
I have 17psi at boiler.
Could I have a bad impeller?

Comment: Perhaps https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/84369/18078 or https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/214595/18078 will help you add water.

Comment: After examining the system, first floor fin tubed are lukewarm. Piping at boiler is hot to touch. I'm thinking impeller.

Comment: A circulator pump circulates. If the system is not essentially full and free of air, it will not overcome that. And if nothing comes out the upper floor bleeder, the system is not full. Solve that problem...

Answer (score 1):

If nothing came out when you bled it, the system is low on fluid/pressure. So the upstairs loop is one or more giant unpressurized bubbles (unless it has valves that isolate it on each end and they are closed for some reason. A single valve won't do that.)

Doesn't matter about the circulator pump at all, and certainly not its fault. It's working fine, apparently, if the downstairs is heating.

Bleeding air from the top of the system can be done with the circulator pump shut right off. What does the pressure gauge on the heating loop show? (That is sometimes part of a pressure-temperature gauge on the boiler.)

Note that there is most likely a leak in the system if the loop pressure is low, so adding more fluid (usually just water) will be a temporary stopgap until the leaks or leaks are fixed.

Comment: Boiler psi is at 17