# How can I repressurise my boiler?

Tags: boiler

My Potterton boiler is flashing an `E118` error code and pressure is dropping below 0.5

I checked few videos online but those have different valves and knobs than mine. Mine have two black knobs and one yellow knob.

How do I go about repressurising the boiler?

[image]

Comment: There does not appear to be a filling valve in the picture you posted. Check the rest of your heating system (pipes and radiators) if you can find something that gives you the idea "I might be able to connect a water hose here".

Comment: You've given us the manufacturer, which is a good start, how about the boiler model number, too? Also, as noted above, is this the _only_ plumbing for the boiler? Are there any other valves or fittings anywhere in the system? It might be in a non-obvious place, like near a water supply instead of near the boiler itself.

Comment: See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/214595/18078 for an example of what you should be looking for, subject to variation across oceans.